# Highlight certain words that appear in sequence

Tags: python, regex, string, iterator

I'm trying to print a text while highlighting certain words and word bigrams. This would be fairly straight forward if I didn't have to print the other tokens like punctuation and such as well.

I have a list of words to highlight and another list of word bigrams to highlight.

Highlighting individual words is fairly easy, like for example:

```
import re
import string

regex_pattern = re.compile("([%s \n])" % string.punctuation)

def highlighter(content, terms_to_hightlight):
    tokens = regex_pattern.split(content)
    for token in tokens:
        if token.lower() in terms_to_hightlight:
            print('\x1b[6;30;42m' + token + '\x1b[0m', end="")
        else:
            print(token, end="")
```

Only highlighting words that appear in sequence is more complex. I have been playing around with iterators but haven't been able to come up with anything that isn't overtly complicated.

Comment: Can you provide an example of cases in which your `highlighter` function works as expected and *not* as expected? Hint: what do "words that appear in sequence" look like to you?

Comment: You could first split the text into a list and then iterate through that list (similar like you already did). Then, you go through that list and check if the current and the next element is a valid bigram, if it is so, you push the words "highlighted" into a separate list. Otherwise, you push it "unhighlighted" into the list. Make sure, to always check if the previous bigram already highlighted the current item (of the new list).

Comment: @not_a_robot He's probably looking for word bigrams, which means two words in a row. He's trying to highlight couple of words if they are in a list of bigrams. This leads to overlapping issues.

Comment: Exactly! I'm trying to highlight words that appear in a list of word bigrams. That means those words should only be highlighted if they actually appear in sequence without any word in between them!

Comment: @Mountain_sheep Welcome to Stack overflow. As your new here I'll just say, there's no need to add the code language in your question; that's all taken care of with tags. By the power of tags and all that! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, one solution is to look ahead to the next word token and check if the bigram is in the list.

```
import re
import string

regex_pattern = re.compile("([%s \n])" % string.punctuation)

def find_next_word(tokens, idx):
    nonword = string.punctuation + " \n"
    for i in range(idx+1, len(tokens)):
        if tokens[i] not in nonword:
            return (tokens[i], i)
    return (None, -1)

def highlighter(content, terms, bigrams):
    tokens = regex_pattern.split(content)
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(tokens):
        token = tokens[idx]
        (next_word, nw_idx) = find_next_word(tokens, idx)
        if token.lower() in terms:
            print('*' + token + '*', end="")
            idx += 1
        elif next_word and (token.lower(), next_word.lower()) in bigrams:
            concat = "".join(tokens[idx:nw_idx+1])
            print('-' + concat + '-', end="")
            idx = nw_idx + 1
        else:
            print(token, end="")
            idx += 1

terms = ['man', 'the']
bigrams = [('once', 'upon'), ('i','was')] 
text = 'Once upon a time, as I was walking to the city, I met a man. As I was tired, I did not look once... upon this man.'
highlighter(text, terms, bigrams)
```

When called, this gives :

```
-Once upon- a time, as -I was- walking to *the* city, I met a *man*. As -I was- tired, I did not look -once... upon- this *man*.
```

Please note that:

- this is a greedy algorithm, it will match the first bigram it finds. So for instance you check for `yellow banana` and `banana boat`, `yellow banana boat` is always highlighted as `-yellow banana- boat`. If you want another behavior, you should update the test logic.
- you probably also want to update the logic to manage the case where a word is both in `terms` and the first part of a bigram
- I haven't tested all edge cases, some things may break / there may be fence-post errors
- you can optimize performance if necessary by:

  - building a list of the first words of the bigram and checking if a word is in it before doing the look-ahead to the next word
  - and/or using the result of the look-ahead to treat in one step all the non-word tokens between two words (implementing this step should be enough to insure linear performance)

Hope this helps.